# Help identifying a 90s children's horror/adventure story featuring an abandoned house, mad scientist, and spider creature

Tags: identification-request

**The key thing I remember about this story:**
In-universe, the folklore goes something like: if you go to the woods, and find the house, and press your face against the glass, there's a sudden horrifying realisation that the reflection you're looking at isn't your own but is the mad scientist looking out at you.

Here is everything else I can recall:

- The story takes place in either city outskirts/suburbs or a small town. The town/main area ends, then there is some amount of field/parkland before a forest takes over, and there is a local folklore about an abandoned house in the forest.
- Supposedly the house belonged to a mad scientist and no one knows what happened to him, he disappeared several (maybe tens of) years ago
- The main characters are kids/teens who go to find the house, get inside and have a snoop around, have an adventure and escape. The main character may have been able to see into the woods from his bedroom at night and may have seen the house lights go on one night.
- They may have found huge amounts of breakfast cereal in the house.

**Things I am not 100% on:**

> Once inside, the MCs discover a labyrinthine sewer/tunnel network under the house and a terrifying spider creature down there. After/during escaping, it is revealed that the spider creature was in fact the scientist who did some sort of experiment on himself and had been living in the tunnels eating breakfast cereal since then.

I was born 1994 and was fairly young when I read this, so I assume it's a 90s/early 2000s book.